# PHP The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, php-7

Before you mark this as duplicate, hear me out. I've tried all the suggestions I can find online. None works. I've restarted countless times. Detailed list of what I've tried below.

Here's my setup:

- Nginx 1.10
- PHP 7.0
- WordPress 4.7
- I'm on a VPS. I have access and control over EVERY single file!

Here's what I want to do:

- Increase the upload file size for my WordPress.

Why?

- Anytime I upload a file size bigger than 2 megabytes, I get this error: `The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.` That's all it tells me.

Here's what I have done:

1. a. So out of common sense, I go into `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` because `php.ini -i` tells me the loaded configuration is from that file. In the `php.ini` file, I change the `upload_max_filesize = 2M` to `upload_max_filesize = 10M`

   b. I go ahead to restart, both Nginx (`sudo service nginx restart`), and PHP (`sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`)

**Above Doesn't work as 2 other approaches below**: I still get:

`The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.`

2. I create my own `user.ini` under `/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/` folder with contents, `upload_max_filesize = 10M`

I go ahead to do 1. b. Still same error

3. They say something is called `error_reporting`. I go ahead to locate the error reporting in my `php.ini` file. I change from the first line below to the second:

   `;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
   error_reporting = E_ALL`

I do 1. b., Still doesn't work.

So what the #&)#(* is wrong with my setup and what again do I have to change somewhere else?

Is it even changeable? I've read and tried almost every single suggestion online, and it never works.

It has never been an issue for me, the 2 max upload, but I'm importing a wordpress xml file, which is just 3 Mb, and I've spent a couple of hours already trying to get this thing to work.

By default, can't the upload size be a bit higher. 2 Megabyte is even ridiculous for a site in recent years. At least 5 is much better.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you are editing the right ini file. Check phoinfo() to verify.

Comment: @RobertRocha How different is `phpinfo()` from `php -i` in the terminal?

Comment: @RobertRocha Yep, they're different. I was stupid to think they're the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at the php.ini file for the CLI, you need to look at the PHP ini file for the web server you're running. Within the WP directory, create a temporary php file, and have it contain `<?php phpinfo();` navigate to that file in the browser and find the php.ini file you actually need to change, then make the change as required.

**NOTE: Remove this file once you're done with your checks, having this information visible to the public is a security risk**

Comment: You have only pointed out something I NEVER knew, that the running WordPress php.ini is different from the actual php.ini thing in `php.ini`. Thank you SOOO MUCH

Comment: No worries, different .ini files exist for very good reasons ( security / resource management etc ) there's a bunch of resources on the php.net site about the settings within the .ini files

Answer (score 3):

**Case 1 : Add php.ini in wp-admin folder**

Navigate to wp-admin folder. Scroll down to see if you have a php.ini file in there.If you didn’t add one at some point.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

**Case 2 : Add code to .htaccess**

Open or create the .htaccess file in the root folder and add the following code:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Answer (score 2):

Initially, I tried *JezEmery* 's answer, but for me the solution came when typed on terminal

```
    locate php.ini
```

and I took among else as printout

```
    /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-development
    /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production
    /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-production.cli
    /usr/lib/php/7.1/php.ini-development
    /usr/lib/php/7.1/php.ini-production
    /usr/lib/php/7.1/php.ini-production.cli
```

then change the php7.1 files, as my apache used version 7.1 of php, and last, I **restarted apache** via

```
    systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using php-fpm but not Apache, sometimes after doing all the above, you need to restart the `php7.4-fpm` service. It may be named differently depending on your PHP version.

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.4-fpm
```

Comment: It Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add these lines of codes in 
**C:/xampp/php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

After restart the xampp control and check the panel it'll increase the file size

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into theme's function.php file

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

OR

Create php.ini into root folder with below lines:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

Add code into .htaccess file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

Comment: Link may not work in future, include explanation and/or example

Comment: A "link" to a "tutorial" won't help the guy; this is a "specific" problem. Edit: This comment as per original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41464226/1

Comment: i have removed link.

Answer (score 0):

What does `php -i | grep 'upload_max_filesize'` give you? The `10M` you set or a different value. If it's giving you the latter then you're editing the wrong php.ini file. You can use `php --ini` to figure which config file is loaded

Comment: this is more a question / comment, to which you have enough rep for.

Comment: The `php -i` was a false place for me to look. Doing the `phpinfo()` actually showed me the *actual* `php.ini` WordPress instance was and is using.

Answer (score 0):

In [cwp](https://control-webpanel.com/) (control web panel) if you use php-fpm, you have to modify `php.ini` in this directory: `/opt/alt`. Or you can do it from control panel: Dashboard>PHP Settings>PHP-FPM Selector> PHP-FPM x.x >Edit php.ini an after change `upload_max_filesize` , reload PHP using related (yellow) button in the left.

[source](http://forum.centos-webpanel.com/index.php?topic=6838.0)